# C++ Specific Sound Output?

Tags: audio, c++

I want to hook a circuit up to my computer, which uses the audio output as an AC current, passes certain frequencies, then rectifies it to a few LEDs, so if I write a program that lets you create a specific pattern and combination of LEDs to be lit, it would output specific frequency sounds.

How do I play a sound at a specific frequency using C++?

Possible?

Comment: What OS are you using? Any particular libraries/frameworks?

Comment: Depends entirely on the device and device driver.

Comment: Closed.  Without an answer to James and Gabe's queries, there is no way for us to provide you with a meaningful answer.  Note that even with that information, you should still research this question yourself and not ask for information until you get stuck.  Though you also run the risk of being closed for being too localized if your question is about the specific details of your circuit.  In that situation, I recommend asking for help on a discussion board about the specific circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with OpenAL.

You would need to generate an array containing PCM encoded data that represents your desired output, then call alBufferData() on your array with the desired sampling frequency and format. See page 21 of the [OpenAL Programmers Guide](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf) for the format required by the alBufferData() function.

For example, the following code plays a 100hz tone.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "OpenAL32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "alut.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  alutInit(&argc, argv);
  alGetError();

  ALuint buffer;
  alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

  {
    // Creating a buffer that hold about 1.5 seconds of audio data.
    char data[32 * 1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32 * 1024; ++i)
    {
      // get a value in the interval [0, 1) over the length of a second
      float intervalPerSecond = static_cast<float>(i % 22050) / 22050.0f;

      // increase the frequency to 100hz
      float intervalPerHundreth = fmod(intervalPerSecond * 100.0f, 1.0f);

      // translate to the interval [0, 2PI)
      float x = intervalPerHundreth * 2 * 3.14159f;

      // and then convert back to the interval [0, 255] for our amplitude data.
      data[i] = static_cast<char>((sin(x) + 1.0f) / 2.0f * 255.0f);
    }

    alBufferData(buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, data, 32 * 1024, 22050);
  }

  ALuint source;
  alGenSources(1, &source);

  alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);

  alSourcePlay(source);

  system("pause");

  alSourceStop(source);

  alDeleteSources(1, &source);

  alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);

  alutExit();

  return 0;
}
```